# Use git diff as diff algorithm in SmartGit

Tags: smartgit

I want to use `git diff` command instead of native SmartGit's diff because I find it better.
SmartGit has customizable external diff, but as far as I understand this setting expects some executable file, not any arbitrary command like `git diff`.
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

[image: Trying this]
[image: Doesn't work]

P.S.: images are broken right now due to Imgur's error, but they are just showing the menu and the error so it's not critical.

Comment: For which purpose exactly do you want to use "git diff"? Please give an example of what you are currently seeing and what you want to see.

Comment: @mstrap SmartGit's diff sometimes produces strange diffs. I crafted simple example:
https://i.imgur.com/vMLA1Gw.png  
It finds some similar piece in the middle of strings and does what you see on the screenshot. Whereas even default `git diff` sees this change as complete replacement:
https://i.imgur.com/Jr9kX9u.png

Comment: Git's diff is line based, while SmartGit's diff will inspect changes within lines, too. You may switch this behavior off by **Changes|Settings**, section **Compare** and here set **Inner-Line Comparison** to **Off**.

Comment: @mstrap, thanks, that's actually another solution to my problem. But there's caveat — option you mentioned is not saved permanently. Even reopening «Log» window resets it.

Comment: For the **Changes** view, you have to use **Changes|Remember as Default**. For the Compare windows, there is similar functionality in the corresponding configuration dialogs.

Comment: @mstrap, thanks, that did the trick! This option is not super-intuitive.